# RMALLET java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Ljava/io/File;.<init>([Ljava/lang/String;)

Tags: java, nosuchmethoderror, rjava

There is an issue when I run RMALLET model, the model is developed based on java.

Here is my code:

```
stop_vector <- readLines(stopwords_en)
debates.instances.short <- 
                mallet.import(text.array = debates[["text"]], 
                stoplist = stop_vector)
```

Then,the error was appeared:

```
Error in mallet.import(text.array = debates[["text"]], stoplist = stop_vector) :
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Ljava/io/File;.<init>([Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

Does anyone know how to sort it out?

Comment: This kind of error normally happens when some compiled code tries to call a method that isn't available at runtime. This could happen if the code is compiled using a different library version than what's available at runtime. Try to make sure you recompile all of your code and use the same version at compile and runtime.

Comment: when I tried to remove the non-letter patterns by token-regex. function, then there is a warning message added below the previous error:  Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="": file name is not correct